# Pyspark Jupyter Error

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, anaconda

I am running the following simple code in my Jupyter notebook and I got the following error:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext("local", "My App")
one_through_9 = range(1,10)
parallel = sc.parallelize(one_through_9, 3)
parallel.count()

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-c394a330f44c> in <module>()
      1 one_through_9 = range(1,10)
      2 parallel = sc.parallelize(one_through_9, 3)
----> 3 parallel.count()

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/Users/myuser/anaconda3": error=13, Permission denied
```

I did all permission to anaconda3 folder but the problem is still persist.